# Как передать переменную-строку в качестве индекса в массив?

Tags: php

Допустим, есть строка `$str="1234"`, теперь я хочу передать эту строку в качестве индекса в массив: `$mas[$str]="hello"`. Но проблема в том, что `"hello"` записывается не в `$mas['1234']`, а в `$mas[1234]`, то есть моя строка автоматически конвертируется в число. Как можно этого избежать? Мне нужно обращаться к индексу `'1234'` именно как к строке. Перепробовал много методов - приведение типов, заключение `$str` в кавычки и другие.

Comment: Строка содержащая число будет преобразована в числовой индекс http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Visman то есть обойти это никак нельзя?

Comment: А зачем Вам принципиально число? Лучше преобразуйте `(int)` ключ, а не пытайтесь извратить политику PHP на счёт ключей.

Comment: @Nik, строка "01234" в числовой индекс не будет преобразована. Так что используйте строки не похожие на числа и все.

Comment: @Visman, решил добавлять в конец числа символ `_`. Это нормальное решение?

Comment: Нет это решение называют "кастыль" разберитесь с тем что хотите, на первый взгляд не вижу разницы написать `$array['12']` или `$array[12]`

Comment: @Naumov у меня числа 8-значные и иногда отрицательные. Именно поэтому, я и думал хранить их как строки... Ведь так `$a[67498342]` как то не очень выглядит.

Comment: так без пробле int может быть отрицательным это нормально

Comment: @Naumov это да, меня большие значения напрягают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php

> Строки, содержащие целое число будут преобразованы к типу integer. Например, ключ со значением "8" будет в действительности сохранен со значением 8. С другой стороны, значение "08" не будет преобразовано, так как оно не является корректным десятичным целым.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mas[(string)$str]="hello";
```

или

```
$mas[strval($str)]="hello";
```

Comment: Нет. Я пробовал и то, и другое, всё равно записывается в числовой индекс.